# Copying a existing database from assets folder to internal database folder error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have this database named **palavras.db**:

[image: palavras.db]

It is placed inside my **res folder**:

[image: inside res folder]

And I use the database like this:

```
public class UserListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  /* As soon as this activity starts, it sets it's recycler view's adapter as 
   list of words from a result from a query */

  private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
  private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
  private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    List<Word> words =  db.search();

    mAdapter = new WordAdapter(words);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }
```

Database class:

```
public class Database {
  private SQLiteDatabase db;
  private String tableName = "'PALAVRAS'";
  private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

  public Database(Context context) {
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    databaseHelper.createDatabase();
    databaseHelper.openDatabase();
  }

  public List<Word> search() {
    return databaseHelper.search(tableName);
  }
```

Database helper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private String DB_PATH = "";
  private static final String DB_NAME = "palavras.db";
  private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
  private final Context mContext;

  public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
    Log.d("porra", DB_PATH);
  }

  public void createDatabase() {
    boolean dbExists = checkDatabase();
    if(dbExists) {

    } else {
      this.getReadableDatabase();
      try {
        copyDatabase();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
      String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
      checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
      checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
  }

  private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
  }

  public void openDatabase() throws SQLiteException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void close() {
    if (mDatabase != null) {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
    super.close();
  }

  public List<Word> search(String tableName) {
    List<Word> list = new ArrayList<Word>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"original", "traduzido"};

    Cursor c = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tableName, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
      while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
        Log.d("Porra", "Table Name=> "+c.getString(0));
        c.moveToNext();
      }
    }
    /*
    Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, colunas, null, null, null, null, "original ASC");

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
      cursor.moveToFirst();

      do {
        Word w = new Word();
        w.setOriginal(cursor.getString(0));
        w.setTraduzido(cursor.getString(1));
        list.add(w);
      } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    */
    // dbCore.close();
    return list;
  }
```

And everything I run it here is what I get:

> 08-01 19:20:45.723 4453-4453/app.visage.testesql E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 32456 of [bda77dda96]
>       08-01 19:20:45.723 4453-4453/app.visage.testesql E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:32456: (2) open(/data/data/app.visage.testesql/databases/palavras.db) - 
>       08-01 19:20:45.725 4453-4453/app.visage.testesql E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/app.visage.testesql/databases/palavras.db'.
>                                                                          android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
>                                                                              at app.visage.testesql.database.DatabaseHelper.checkDatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:53)
>                                                                              at app.visage.testesql.database.DatabaseHelper.createDatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:36)
>                                                                              at app.visage.testesql.database.Database.(Database.java:27)
>                                                                              at app.visage.testesql.activities.UserListActivity.onCreate(UserListActivity.java:32)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>       08-01 19:20:45.760 4453-4453/app.visage.testesql D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       08-01 19:20:45.761 4453-4453/app.visage.testesql E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: app.visage.testesql, PID: 4453
>                                                                          java.lang.Error: Error copying database
>                                                                              at app.visage.testesql.database.DatabaseHelper.createDatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:44)
>                                                                              at app.visage.testesql.database.Database.(Database.java:27)
>                                                                              at app.visage.testesql.activities.UserListActivity.onCreate(UserListActivity.java:32)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Failed to copy database and failed to open it.

Is there something wrong with my code that I can't just see?

Also, when I browse to my database folder I see it was copied there! but not entirely, table **PALAVRAS** was not present, only **android_metadata**.

Answer (score 1):

> It is placed inside my res folder

That is not going to work, as your file will not be part of your app. You cannot invent new locations to put files in your project, such as hanging them off of `res/`.

> when i browse to my database folder I see it was copied there

No, it was not.

> but not entirely, table PALAVRAS was not present, only android_metadata.

That was created for you when you created the empty database.

Either:

1. [Use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), which provides you with a simple library to replace most of the code in your question
2. Read the code that you copied and pasted into your project, which shows that the original database is being copied from assets

In either case, your database will go into the `assets/` directory, not the `res/` directory.